# move_uploaded_file not working (php, nginx)

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to use php function move_uploaded_file on production server and there is some strange error. Some files can be and some files can't be uploaded. Everything works on localhost.

```
// test for errors
if (!empty($file['errors'])) {
    log('ERR uploadImages: errors occured');
} else {
    log('OK uploadImages: errors empty');
}

// test is dir
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    log("ERR uploadImages: is_dir {$path}");
} else {
    log('OK uploadImages: is_dir');
}

// test on writable
if (!is_writable($path)) {
    log('ERR uploadImages: is_writable');
} else {
    log('OK uploadImages: is_writable');
}

// upload this file
$uploaded = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filepath);

// is uploaded?
if ($uploaded) {
    log('OK uploadImages: uploaded');
} else {
    log('ERR uploadImages: not uploaded');
}
```

And my log is:

```
OK uploadImages: errors empty
OK uploadImages: is_dir  
OK uploadImages: is_writable
ERR uploadImages: not uploaded
```

Some of files are uploaded, some not.
In example:

```
jpeg 1.65MB - ERR
jpeg 1.48MB - ERR
jpeg 1.2MB - ERR
jpeg 0.9MB - OK
jpg 0.5MB - OK
mp3 6MB - ERR
```

So I have checked php.ini

```
post_max_size   100M
upload_max_filesize 600M
```

Comment: post_max_size must be larger or equal to upload_max_filesize (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: Remember to restart your HTTP server after modifying the ini

Comment: Do you have free space in folder for copy files?

Comment: Do you check the right `php.ini` file? Did you change that ini values recently without a service restart?

Comment: You're checking if `$path` is a directory, and if `$path` is writable, but you're copying it to `$filepath`. Are you sure you have access to the `$filepath` directory?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you're right. 

    $path is in example /my/path/ ,
    $filepath is /my/path/filename.ext - because second parameter must not be dir

Comment: @ManicDepression Aha - yeah that makes sense - for your own (and other programmers) sake, please rename it do `$dirpath` or something similar. Have you checked if it's the correct ini file you're editing? What does `var_dump( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) )` and `var_dump( ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' ) )` tell you?

Comment: @h2ooooooo string(4) "100M" string(4) "600M", which is correct. Server was restarted

Comment: If you enable errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` do you see any `E_NOTICE` or `E_WARNING` messages?

Comment: @h2ooooooo nope, without errors

Comment: @ManicDepression And what does `$file` look like? It's definitely not a normal file upload object, as it's called `['error']` and not `['errors']`. Could you do a `var_dump` of it with a working file and one without?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I maybe found it - it looks like NGINX has his own config to 1MB - client_max_body_size 1M;
I let you know when server admin responds to me. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NGINX has his own config set to 1MB - client_max_body_size 1M;

Solved